# Is it safe to remove KVM from a F25 workstation with no virtualization needs?

Tags: fedora, package-management, kvm, bridge

I installed Fedora 25 on some AMD hardware. I noticed a bridge is present after install. It is unusual since I did not install it or ask for a package that would include it. My install is a stock workstation with developer tools.

```
virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:f6:da:cf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`libvirt` and `qemu` are the usual suspects, but they do not appear to be installed:

```
bulldozer$ sudo dnf remove libvirt
No match for argument: libvirt
Error: No packages marked for removal.
bulldozer$ sudo dnf remove qemu
No match for argument: qemu
Error: No packages marked for removal.
```

It looks like KVM is the package (see below). I was not able to find a reason for the pre-installed package.

My question is, is it safe to remove KVM from a headless workstation which only uses SSH for remote access and developer tools? Is KVM now necessary for Fedora to work?

---

```
================================================================================
 Package                         Arch   Version                 Repository
                                                                           Size
================================================================================
Removing:
 SDL2                            x86_64 2.0.5-3.fc25            @updates  1.1 M
 boost-random                    x86_64 1.60.0-10.fc25          @updates   25 k
 boost-thread                    x86_64 1.60.0-10.fc25          @updates  162 k
 celt051                         x86_64 0.5.1.3-11.fc24         @anaconda 112 k
 corosync                        x86_64 2.4.2-1.fc25            @updates  475 k
 corosynclib                     x86_64 2.4.2-1.fc25            @updates  277 k
 cyrus-sasl                      x86_64 2.1.26-26.2.fc24        @anaconda 137 k
 cyrus-sasl-md5                  x86_64 2.1.26-26.2.fc24        @anaconda  84 k
 dmidecode                       x86_64 1:3.0-6.fc25            @updates  215 k
 edk2-ovmf                       noarch 20161105git3b25ca8-1.fc25
                                                                @updates  6.2 M
 genisoimage                     x86_64 1.1.11-31.fc24          @anaconda 1.1 M
 glusterfs                       x86_64 3.9.1-1.fc25            @updates  1.8 M
 glusterfs-api                   x86_64 3.9.1-1.fc25            @updates  170 k
 glusterfs-client-xlators        x86_64 3.9.1-1.fc25            @updates  3.8 M
 glusterfs-fuse                  x86_64 3.9.1-1.fc25            @updates  329 k
 glusterfs-libs                  x86_64 3.9.1-1.fc25            @updates  1.2 M
 gnome-boxes                     x86_64 3.22.3-2.fc25           @updates  5.0 M
 gperftools-libs                 x86_64 2.5-2.fc25              @anaconda 1.3 M
 gtk-vnc2                        x86_64 0.6.0-1.fc25            @anaconda 205 k
 gvnc                            x86_64 0.6.0-1.fc25            @anaconda 241 k
 ipxe-roms-qemu                  noarch 20160622-1.git0418631.fc25
                                                                @anaconda 2.2 M
 libcacard                       x86_64 3:2.5.2-2.fc24          @anaconda  93 k
 libfdt                          x86_64 1.4.2-1.fc25            @anaconda  45 k
 libgovirt                       x86_64 0.3.4-1.fc25            @anaconda 198 k
 libibverbs                      x86_64 1.2.1-1.fc25            @anaconda 123 k
 libiscsi                        x86_64 1.15.0-2.fc24           @anaconda 186 k
 libnfs                          x86_64 1.9.8-2.fc24            @anaconda 284 k
 libphodav                       x86_64 2.1-1.fc25              @updates  109 k
 libqb                           x86_64 1.0.1-1.fc25            @updates  187 k
 librados2                       x86_64 1:10.2.4-2.fc25         @updates  6.4 M
 librbd1                         x86_64 1:10.2.4-2.fc25         @updates  7.8 M
 librdmacm                       x86_64 1.1.0-1.fc25            @anaconda 136 k
 libusal                         x86_64 1.1.11-31.fc24          @anaconda 450 k
 libvirt-daemon                  x86_64 2.2.0-2.fc25            @updates  2.5 M
 libvirt-daemon-config-network   x86_64 2.2.0-2.fc25            @updates  228
 libvirt-daemon-driver-interface x86_64 2.2.0-2.fc25            @updates  112 k
 libvirt-daemon-driver-network   x86_64 2.2.0-2.fc25            @updates  534 k
 libvirt-daemon-driver-nodedev   x86_64 2.2.0-2.fc25            @updates  112 k
 libvirt-daemon-driver-nwfilter  x86_64 2.2.0-2.fc25            @updates  169 k
 libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu      x86_64 2.2.0-2.fc25            @updates  1.3 M
 libvirt-daemon-driver-secret    x86_64 2.2.0-2.fc25            @updates   83 k
 libvirt-daemon-driver-storage   x86_64 2.2.0-2.fc25            @updates  658 k
 libvirt-daemon-kvm              x86_64 2.2.0-2.fc25            @updates    0
 libvirt-gconfig                 x86_64 1.0.0-1.fc25            @updates  359 k
 libvirt-glib                    x86_64 1.0.0-1.fc25            @updates  257 k
 libvirt-gobject                 x86_64 1.0.0-1.fc25            @updates  216 k
 libvirt-libs                    x86_64 2.2.0-2.fc25            @updates   22 M
 libwsman1                       x86_64 2.6.2-7.fc25            @anaconda 322 k
 lttng-ust                       x86_64 2.8.1-2.fc25            @anaconda 977 k
 lzop                            x86_64 1.03-15.fc25            @anaconda 103 k
 netcf-libs                      x86_64 0.2.8-4.fc24            @anaconda 199 k
 numactl-libs                    x86_64 2.0.11-2.fc24           @anaconda  45 k
 numad                           x86_64 0.5-21.20150602git.fc24 @anaconda  56 k
 qemu-common                     x86_64 2:2.7.1-2.fc25          @updates  1.0 M
 qemu-img                        x86_64 2:2.7.1-2.fc25          @updates  4.2 M
 qemu-kvm                        x86_64 2:2.7.1-2.fc25          @updates    0
 qemu-system-x86                 x86_64 2:2.7.1-2.fc25          @updates   20 M
 radvd                           x86_64 2.14-1.fc25             @anaconda 179 k
 seabios-bin                     noarch 1.9.3-1.fc25            @anaconda 647 k
 seavgabios-bin                  noarch 1.9.3-1.fc25            @anaconda 230 k
 sgabios-bin                     noarch 1:0.20110622svn-9.fc24  @anaconda 4.0 k
 sheepdog                        x86_64 1.0.1-2.fc25            @updates  851 k
 spice-glib                      x86_64 0.33-2.fc25             @anaconda 1.3 M
 spice-gtk3                      x86_64 0.33-2.fc25             @anaconda 257 k
 spice-server                    x86_64 0.13.3-1.fc25           @updates  1.2 M
 systemd-container               x86_64 231-12.fc25             @updates  955 k
 usbredir                        x86_64 0.7.1-2.fc24            @anaconda  96 k
 userspace-rcu                   x86_64 0.9.2-2.fc25            @anaconda 292 k
 virglrenderer                   x86_64 0.5.0-1.20160411git61846f92f.fc25
                                                                @anaconda 1.8 M
 vte3                            x86_64 0.36.5-2.fc24           @anaconda 987 k
 xen-libs                        x86_64 4.7.1-6.fc25            @updates  1.5 M
 xen-licenses                    x86_64 4.7.1-6.fc25            @updates  389 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Remove  72 Packages

Installed size: 109 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

Answer (score 4):

### 1. "libvirt and qemu are the usual suspects"

> but they do not appear to be installed

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides /lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service
libvirt-daemon-2.2.0-2.fc25.x86_64
```

There's an alternative to removing the package:

```
systemctl disable --now libvirtd.service
```

Or if you want to make sure no software can request libvirtd to start:

```
systemctl mask --now libvirt.service
```

---

You might have found this looking in the list of running services (`systemctl`) or processes (`ps -ax` / `ps ax`).  If you found the process ID first, there's a neat trick to get the service even if the name was different.

```
$ ps -ax|grep libvirt
  992 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/libvirtd
 1365 ?        S      0:00 /sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/libexec/libvirt_leaseshelper
 1366 ?        S      0:00 /sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/libexec/libvirt_leaseshelper
 6997 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto libvirt
$ systemctl status 992
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-02-04 13:15:19 GMT; 3h 41min ago
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           http://libvirt.org
 Main PID: 992 (libvirtd)
    Tasks: 18 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
           ├─ 992 /usr/sbin/libvirtd
           ├─1365 /sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/libexec/libvirt_leaseshelper
           └─1366 /sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/libexec/libvirt_leaseshelper

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

---

### 2. "I was not able to find a reason for the pre-installed package"

> ```
> ...
> gnome-boxes
> ```

```
$ dnf info gnome-boxes|grep Summary
Summary     : A simple GNOME 3 application to access remote or virtual systems
```

### 3. "Is it safe to remove KVM"

> from a headless workstation which only uses SSH for remote access and developer tools? Is KVM now necessary for Fedora to work?

Your removal list looks fine to me.

It doesn't even uninstall GNOME.  Note that commands like `dnf remove systemd` or `dnf remove dnf` would warn about removing "protected packages".  However, I understand the concern that some important package might be removed, which is not a strict package dependency.  You can reduce what you need to review:

On Debian, I would use `apt-get remove X`.  It would show me the removed packages, and *separately* show me packages which can be "autoremoved" as they are no longer depended on by any package.

The result makes it clearer that you're only removing `libvirt`, `gnome-boxes`, and a library called `libguestfs` which depends on libvirt (but which nothing else depends on).

libguestfs has/is used by some very cool tools.  `virt-sparsify` can be used (with libvirt disabled, if you run it as root) to take a sparse image of a partitioned removable drive.

EDIT: I noticed that `dnf remove` on Fedora 26 will already show separate lists for "Removing dependent packages", and "Removing unused dependencies".  Yay!  I don't remember it doing this before.

If your `dnf` command did not appear to show separate lists, there is a more obscure approach, to make it behave like `apt-get` and not include the automatic `autoremove` of unused dependencies.

```
# dnf remove --setopt "clean_requirements_on_remove=0" libvirt-daemon 
Dependencies resolved.
======================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                            Arch                      Version                               Repository                   Size
======================================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 gnome-boxes                                        x86_64                    3.22.3-2.fc25                         @updates                    5.0 M
 libguestfs                                         x86_64                    1:1.34.3-1.fc25                       @fedora                     3.8 M
 libguestfs-tools-c                                 x86_64                    1:1.34.3-1.fc25                       @fedora                      15 M
 libguestfs-xfs                                     x86_64                    1:1.34.3-1.fc25                       @fedora                       9  
 libvirt-daemon                                     x86_64                    2.2.0-2.fc25                          @updates                    2.5 M
 libvirt-daemon-config-network                      x86_64                    2.2.0-2.fc25                          @updates                    228  
 libvirt-daemon-driver-interface                    x86_64                    2.2.0-2.fc25                          @updates                    112 k
 libvirt-daemon-driver-network                      x86_64                    2.2.0-2.fc25                          @updates                    534 k
 libvirt-daemon-driver-nodedev                      x86_64                    2.2.0-2.fc25                          @updates                    112 k
 libvirt-daemon-driver-nwfilter                     x86_64                    2.2.0-2.fc25                          @updates                    169 k
 libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu                         x86_64                    2.2.0-2.fc25                          @updates                    1.3 M
 libvirt-daemon-driver-secret                       x86_64                    2.2.0-2.fc25                          @updates                     83 k
 libvirt-daemon-driver-storage                      x86_64                    2.2.0-2.fc25                          @updates                    658 k
 libvirt-daemon-kvm                                 x86_64                    2.2.0-2.fc25                          @updates                      0  

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================================================================================
Remove  14 Packages

Installed size: 29 M
Is this ok [y/N]
```

(Then afterwards, I would use `dnf autoremove`).

Answer (score 3):

It is safe to remove KVM. It is installed by default on Workstation because it's a common software developer use case. If you don't need it, you can remove it. (On the other hand, the overhead of it being there is fairly small, all things considered, so you could also just ignore it.)

Comment: Nitpick: I don't think gcc or git are installed by default. I'd attribute it to GNOME Boxes being a thing... it's not just that VM tech is common, it's that there's a nice simple on-ramp for it in this DE.

Comment: Nitpick or not, this is the actual explanation for why GNOME Boxes is included by default in Fedora Workstation. It's true that GCC isn't in the default package set, but Git is.